# JSON object in PHP with property

Tags: php, json

What would be the equivalent PHP array structure to create an object with identical properties:

For example... create the object 'columns' below in PHP using json_encode:

```
jQuery('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajaxSource": "sources/objects.txt",
  "columns": [
    { "data": "engine" },
    { "data": "browser" },
    { "data": "platform" },
    { "data": "version" },
    { "data": "grade" }
  ]
} );
```

(I am trying to build a dynamic datatable and define the columns in the source JSON.

Comment: why not simply `json_decode(YOUR_JSON);` ?

Comment: I am using json_decode... but I'm not sure of how to create the structure in PHP that json_decode will output with that structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ArrayObject

```
new ArrayObject([
 "ajaxSource" => "...",
  "columns" => [
    new ArrayObject(['data' => 'engine']),
    new ArrayObject(['data' => 'browser']),
    new ArrayObject(['data' => 'etc'])
  ]
]);
```

if you want to assemble this you need to store the objects inside an array like

```
$columns = [];
for(...) {
$columns[] = new ArrayObject(['data' => 'etc']);
}
```

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/de/arrayobject.construct.php

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... If I do the following: 

$object = new ArrayObject(["title"=>"x"]);
$object = new ArrayObject(["title"=>"y"]);
$object = new ArrayObject(["title"=>"z"]);

The result is just: 

{
    "title": "z"
}

Comment: @FishBulbX you need use $object[] instead of $object. Without [], you just assign a bunch of value into $object, of course the last value will override everything prior. With [], php will recognize this is an array, and add new values into the tail of the array.